# How can I get a specific argument from a previous command in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, command-line-arguments

In bash, you can use `!*` to get all the arguments from the previous command. As an example, if you did `cp /some/path /some/other/path` and then did `mv !*`, the second command would be expanded to `mv /some/path /some/other/path`.

Is there anything like this that can be used to access a specific argument from a command instead of all of them?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In `!*`, `!` is the [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) prefix, and `*` is the [word designator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Designators) that means all arguments. You can memorize the general syntax as bang-line-colon-column (`!`line`:`column). There are many possible shortcuts: the default line is the previous line, the default column specifier is “all”, and you can leave off the colon if the column specifier is non-numeric (but `!3` would mean line 3). You can use `!:0` to refer to the command name, `!:1`, `!:2`, etc, to refer to successive arguments, `!:$` for the last word, `!:*` for all arguments, and more.

See also [this post by Michael Mrozek](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/67#67) at [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I tried it myself and this didn't work, however. After looking at the post by Michale Mrozek, it says to use `!:1`, `!:2`. After using the version with the colons, it worked.

Comment: @MrMan: Oops, right, if you leave off the colon with a number, the number is interpreted as a line number. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. So, then I assume that doing `!1:1` would point to the first argument of the first line?

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I really dislike this “expansion with exclamation mark” feature which will even disturb if you try `echo "Hello World!"` in interactive shells (so sourcing scripts that assume they will be run in non-interactive mode won't work at all).

So, I set `set +o histexpand` and start recalling arguments with the following method:

```
Esc, 1, Esc, Ctrl-Y => Insert first argument of previous command.
```

Note that the Esc-trick is because I don't have a meta key.

Comment: I almost never use exclamation points in commands. So the Exclamation point method works perfectly for me.

Comment: Then enjoy it. Many of the numerous features of your shell are designed for only a few users.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to escape exclamation points. Do `echo 'Hello, orld!'`. Note the single quotes instead of double ones.